# MongoDB - How to access value field without defining key

Tags: java, mongodb, processing

Can someone advice on how to access a value in a MongoDb?
I am using Processing/Java, and for now I am using the following to access all values of a specific field that I am interested. However, as the key value is a timestamp and cannot explicitly define it, I would simply like to get all values and store them in an array.

Can someone show me how this is done?

```
  BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_sensor", getFieldValue);
  cursor = coll.find(query);

  try {
    while (cursor.hasNext ()) {
      DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
      Object valueField = theObj.get("values");
      println(valueField);
    }
  } 
  finally {
    cursor.close();
  }
```

Here is the result that I get from the database query:

```
{ "1414879800000" : "38" , "1414879860000" : "29" , "1414879920000" : "30" , "1414879980000" : "31" , "1414880040000" : "24" , "1414880100000" : "41" , "1414897380000" : "28"
```

Therefore I would like a new array with values of: `["38", "29", "30", "31", "24", "41", "28"]`

Comment: Can you post a sample document in your collection? There are two ways to achieve this - aggregate the result or perform the transformation in Java, it would be clear if you could post the document structure.

Comment: Is this ok?
http://soniconlab.com/images/db.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `values` field is a map, it is not possible to get it as an array using the aggregation framework. So you need to live with iterating the `values` map in the client side and retrieving its values to store them in a list.

To iterate the map, `values` should be type casted to an `BasicDBObject` which in turn implements the Map in hierarchy and **not** to a `Object`.

Your modified code would look like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_sensor", getFieldValue);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
List<String> v = null;

try 
{
    while (cursor.hasNext()) 
    {
        v = new ArrayList<String>();
        DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
        BasicDBObject valueField = (BasicDBObject) theObj.get("values");

        Set<String> keys = valueField.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iter = keys.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) 
        {
            v.add(valueField.getString(iter.next()));
        }
        System.out.println(v);
    }
} 
finally 
{
    cursor.close();
}
```